# How to search a table in Data Google Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have created a table in Google Data Studio with two columns(labels,count). I have 10,000 labels and would like the ability to search by label instead of scrolling through a list of 10,000 labels in alphabetical order to find a specific label. Any solutions for this out of the box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can fix this problem by inserting a filter control.

for example,

i had created a table in data studio with two columns (**medium and sessions**)

[image: medium and sessions]

then insert a filter control

[image: filter control]

and Set its dimension as medium and metric as session.

Like this:

[image: dimension/metric value]

if you want set values of the table as ascending, change the metric value as ascending.

[image: ascending or descending]

see my data studio report it have filter control and a table with two columns (**medium and sessions**)

[image: filter control and table]

finally, you can search the table values of medium by inserting filter control.

[image: search box in filter control]

I'm going to enter a value (**value:banner**) in search box of filter control and tables shows only the values of search term "**banner**".

[image: final output]

Comment: Thanks that is what I was looking for :)